# Clash of Clan - Uploading a second account onto the same device

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hopefully this question hasn't been answer already and if it had - I'm sorry.

I currently have a level 77 account under exampleAAA@gmail.com on my android phone. Also, I have a level 60 on my android tablet under exampleBBB@gmail.com. I'm trying to load my level 60 onto my phone, but get that "type CONFIRM to load this account." MY QUESTION is if I proceed - will I lose all progress of my level 77 account permanently? Or can I always reload the progress by signing into exampleAAA@gmail.com again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have linked both villages with gmail accounts it shouldn't be a problem, and you cannot actually replace a village with another using the same gmail. So it should be safe for you to switch between the two.

I am saying this because I linked a new village (by mistake) to my email account and was trying to replace it with my real village but it won't let me (even COC support couldn't help me and they suggested I create another gmail account to link it)

Answer (score 1):

Note: My answer is only for Android as I do not know if this works for iDevices.

You will not lose any progress as long as each village is linked to a separate email account. Once that is done, all you have to do is disconnect from one account and connect to the other and complete the CONFIRM prompt. After you complete the CONFIRM prompt it will load the village that is associated with the email you just connected to.

Source: I have this set up and do it pretty much daily.

Answer (score -2):

Make two Google Accounts, sign in the game with the new account, go to settings>connect with the new account and delete all data of game. Do not install game then sign in.